# SwipeRefreshLayout on a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

On a `ListView`, the `SwipeRefreshLayout`  works fine. However, on a `LinearLayout` only (without `ListView`) the behaviour is bizarre. The `SwiperefreshLayout's` progress bar doesn't appear completely, in fact, it just appears for a fraction of second. What can the issue be?

Answer (score 33):

In your `LinearLayout` which is inside the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, set **`android:clickable="true"`**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dummy_view"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: Yes it works, but why we need to set clickable=true?

Comment: Yeah worked for me too. why was it so that when you add `clickable` the `SwipeRefreshLayout` works?

Comment: This did work for me as well. Just wondering what must be the actual reason for this working.